# Multiple results for one expression in C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, avr-gcc

trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814166/preprocessor-missing-binary-operator-before-token), I reduced my code to a minimum to find errors and check the results of expressions `F_CPU` is defined in the main file.

```
#ifndef USART_H_
#define USART_H_

#include <avr/io.h>



#define USART_BAUDRATE          4800
#define USART_BSCALE            -3

#if USART_BSCALE < 0
    #define USART_BSEL          ((F_CPU / 16) * (1<<(-1*USART_BSCALE)) / USART_BAUDRATE - (1<<(-1*USART_BSCALE)))
    #if (USART_BSEL < 0)
        #pragma message "BSEL < 0"
    #elif (USART_BSEL == 0)
        #pragma message "BSEL = 0"
    #elif (USART_BSEL > 0)
        #pragma message "BSEL > 0"
    #endif
#endif

#endif
```

The result of `USART_BSEL` - calculating with integers only - is 3325. The output is this:

```
#pragma message: BSEL > 0
#pragma message: BSEL < 0
```

How can I get more than one message from this code? And how can they be different?

The output is always two lines, but depending on my use of integer suffixes for `BAUDRATE` and `F_CPU` (I used L, UL and ULL), I get different pragma messages. Why is the preprocessor behaving that way?

Comment: what is the #define for F_CPU?

Comment: Is it included twice?

Comment: To produce exactly these two pragma lines, it is `#define F_CPU 32000000UL`

Comment: #define without parentheses is highly dangerous. You're aiming a gun right at your foot.

Comment: @dbrank0 It is included in the main file and in the USART.c file. But as I understand it, this needs to be done.

Comment: And I only get BSEL > 0 when turning your code to .c and adding F_CPU define.

Comment: Peder: And for each include you get one printout. And something (F_CPU?) changes between inclusions.

Comment: I am also only getting BSEL>0, after removing the avr/io.h include and adding the F_CPU #define. This is on gcc 4.9.3.

Comment: I'm trying to update the compiler. Meanwhile, when I do _not_ include this header file (USART.h) in USART.c, only one and the correct message appear. This raises two problems: 1) As far as I know I _have_ to include the header file it in the c-file and 2) why are the results of the two messages different? (The c-file is empty except for the header inclusion.)

Comment: With given values, it results in `(16000000 / 4800 - 8)`. The magnitude of the 1st summand and the 2nd summand in your macro is very different. It seems `BSEL <= 0` will never occur?

Comment: Since you didn't include your whole project, we have to guess.  My guess:  You include usart.h in multiple C files.  In one of those C files, F_CPU is defined, in another, it is undefined or 0.  There *should* be a warning about F_CPU being used when undefined, but you *could* be compiling with this (or all) warnings turned off.

Comment: @SteveKolokowsky: in an `#if` preprocessing directive, using a name which has not been `#define`d is not an error; the name is simply replaced with 0. I don't believe gcc will warn about this with any commonly-used `-W` setting

Comment: @Peder: FYI: `-1*x` is parsed as though it were written `-(1*x)`, which is obviously the same as `-x`.  So you could just write `-USART_BSCALE` instead of `(-1*USART_BSCALE)`